# CCMoveBy in cocos2d-iphone

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

hello everyone
i use CCMoveBy for keeping a sprite going

```
if (abs(dff.x) > abs(dff.y)) {
    id action = [CCMoveBy actionWithDuration:1 position:ccp(10,10)];
    [sprite runAction:[CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:action]];
}
else {
    id action = [CCMoveBy actionWithDuration:1 position:ccp(5,5)];
    [sprite runAction:[CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:action]];
}
```

if i push the sprite left/right,it will go to left/right,but now when i push it,it will go to the diagonal direction,not left or right or up or down,so what's the right is?thanks

Comment: the answer you got was a good one, mark question as answered please

Answer (score 5):

Are you saying you want to just move on one axis? Then in that case you need to keep one of the values in `ccp()` at 0.

Answer (score 1):

**Move y:** `ccp(0, 10) // 10 points up y axis`

**Move x:** `ccp(10, 0) // 10 points right`

And *invert* axis to - if you want to go opposite way.